# Ext.Net Error in server

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

Am new for Ext.net controls , i have been developed sample forms using Ext.Net controls it has working fine in my local system , but when am uploading in server am getting following error

Please help me

Error 1 Could not load file or assembly 'Ext.Net'or one of its dependencies. Module was expected to have an assembly manifest.

thanks in advance

Comment: Has the bin folder with the dlls been uploaded to the server?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Mr.Daniilya i have uploaded bin folder with all dll files . sorry for asking this questin it may be a silly .. Is it from server side they have to install Ext.net controls?

Comment: They should not install Ext.NET controls on the server. There should be .NET and ASP.NET installed on their side. What is .NET version on the server? Also do you a link online to reproduce the problem?

Comment: and ext.net version is 2.5.2

Comment: Then it should be OK with this part. The problem is something else.

Comment: thak u daniil, it may be a server side issue or my side?

Comment: shall i give u dll file names whicj is in bilfolder

Comment: It is likely a server issue if it works with your local server. As for the file names, it will probably not help me to know better. I've asked about an online test case. It might help. Though, it might not as well.

Comment: Thank u MR.Daniil Veriga